# Are hex private keys already in little endian format?

Tags: cryptography, source, privatekey, spend-key

I implemented my own private (seed) spend and view key generator for learning purposes but I still don't fully understand. I ended up with a working implementation but I feel that I'm just swapping bytes for the sake of just doing it.

Is the 256-bit hex key that any wallet generates in Little or Big Endian format?

e.g.,

We got this private spend key.

`f88c99d397c63ff261129a05ed678050ff6920efaddcb519dd82d18ed709f30b`

If I want to convert it to an integer what would be its value?

`1.124^77` or `5.40^77`

Comment: "that any wallet" is not really answerable, how a particular wallet decides to encode keys is down to the wallet implementation. "We got this private spend key" from *where* did you get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the 256-bit hex key that any wallet generates in Little or Big Endian format?

How a particular wallet exports/displays a key is really implementation specific, but for official Monero code/wallets you'll see the keys in little endian byte order.

> We got this private spend key.
>
> `f88c99d397c63ff261129a05ed678050ff6920efaddcb519dd82d18ed709f30b`
>
> If I want to convert it to an integer what would be its value?

Assuming you got that from some Monero code, it would be:

`5404853098303265536527757675112388573511587645507532015181545700776929234168`

(or with lost precision `5.40485e75`)

Comment: Yes, I got the address from a Monero Key generator online. Now I think it makes sense, whenever we are dealing with a integer of 256 bits, either in hex or binary, we can assume that the scalar is in little-endian format.

Comment: I wouldn't assume anything when using some random online tool. But for *official* Monero code/wallets, it will be displayed in LE order.